# Cleveref mistakenly showing filename in external references

Tags: cleveref, xr-hyper

I am using a combination of `xr-hyper`, `hyperref` and `cleveref` with multiple files.  Old code that I have is no longer working correctly.  The external references now include the file name of the extrenal file, rather just the referenced number.

In the example below, I compile `fileone` first, and then `filetwo`, which refers to the section in `fileone`.  The output of `filetwo` is then

[image]

instead of just `Section 1`.

`fileone.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{One}
\label{sec:one}

\end{document}
```

`filetwo.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\externaldocument{fileone}

\begin{document}

\Cref{sec:one}

\end{document}
```

I suspect some fix to `cleveref` is needed, but have not tracked down exactly what is needed.

For reference the file versions are

```
xr-hyper.sty    2024-01-20 v7.01h eXternal References (DPC)
hyperref.sty    2024-01-20 v7.01h Hypertext links for LaTeX
cleveref.sty    2018/03/27 v0.21.4 Intelligent cross-referencing
```

Comment: Note that cleveref might not be supported anymore

Comment: we added a firstaid to the just released latex-dev, see my edit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Edit 2023-03-28

A firstaid for cleveref has been added to LaTeX which contains the redefinitions mentioned in the answer. With the next LaTeX release and with the latex-dev released today the references will be correct again.

### Old Answer

In a current LaTeX, the syntax of `\newlabel` in the `.aux` file has been unified with the syntax used by [`hyperref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) and always contains five data containers. [`cleveref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) has not been adapted to this change and still only uses two data container in its definition. So your external `.aux` file contains (I added some spaces for better visibility):

```
\newlabel{sec:one}{  {1}  {1}  {One}  {section.1}  {}  }    %<------- five
\newlabel{sec:one@cref}{  {[section][1][]1}  {[1][1][]1}  } %<------- two
```

Inside a document it doesn't matter so much that the [`cleveref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) label has only two data container, as [`cleveref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) is the only one using it. But [`xr-hyper`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xr-hyper) tries to adhere to the new standard too and extends every label it reads to five data container. It also makes use of the fifth data container to store the file name for links.

Now, recently [`xr-hyper`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xr-hyper) has been extended to store always the file name (and not only if the label contains a destination name in the fourth container) to allow file links to the external document even if that document didn't use [`hyperref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). With this change one gets this definitions for the labels from the external document:

```
> \r@sec:one=macro:
->{1}{1}{One}{section.1}{fileone.pdf}.

> \r@sec:one@cref=macro:
->{[section][1][]1}{[1][1][]1}{}{}{fileone.pdf}.
% would be in older versions:
% ->{[section][1][]1}{[1][1][]1}{}{}{}.
```

And then [`cleveref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) falls over the `fileone.pdf` in the last argument.

The best would be if [`cleveref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) would be updated to use the standard five data container always too, so that everything is in sync. For now, you can do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\externaldocument{fileone}

\makeatletter
\def\cref@getref#1#2{%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter#2\csname r@#1@cref\endcsname%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter#2%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\@firstoffive#2}}% <-------- five
\def\cpageref@getref#1#2{%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter#2\csname r@#1@cref\endcsname%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter#2%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
      \expandafter\@secondoffive#2}}% <----------- five
      
\AtBeginDocument{%
   \def\label@noarg#1{%
    \cref@old@label{#1}%
    \@bsphack%
    \edef\@tempa{{page}{\the\c@page}}%
    \setcounter{page}{1}%
    \edef\@tempb{\thepage}%
    \expandafter\setcounter\@tempa%
    \cref@constructprefix{page}{\cref@result}%
    \protected@write\@auxout{}%
      {\string\newlabel{#1@cref}{{\cref@currentlabel}%
      {[\@tempb][\arabic{page}][\cref@result]\thepage}{}{}{}}}% <----- five
    \@esphack}%
  \def\label@optarg[#1]#2{%
    \cref@old@label{#2}%
    \@bsphack%
    \edef\@tempa{{page}{\the\c@page}}%
    \setcounter{page}{1}%
    \edef\@tempb{\thepage}%
    \expandafter\setcounter\@tempa%
    \cref@constructprefix{page}{\cref@result}%
    \protected@edef\cref@currentlabel{%
      \expandafter\cref@override@label@type%
        \cref@currentlabel\@nil{#1}}%
    \protected@write\@auxout{}%
      {\string\newlabel{#2@cref}{{\cref@currentlabel}%
      {[\@tempb][\arabic{page}][\cref@result]\thepage}{}{}{}}}% <------- five
    \@esphack}%
    }           
\begin{document}

\Cref{sec:one}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\labelformat`  is also a step in the right direction. Hopefully one day all these packages will be consolidated in either hyperref or the kernel.

Comment: Thank you for digging through this.  I hope some fix can be added to cleveref at some stage.

Comment: Any chance this is fixed before the upcoming TexLive 2024 release?

Comment: @Flow the maintainer has been notified but I don't know if and if yes when he will fix it, you will have to ask him directly. If nothing happens we will probably add a firstaid to the next LaTeX release as a temporary fix.

Comment: What's the recommended cleveref alternative these days, if any?

Comment: @flow don't ask such follow up questions in comments. That pings only me and so requests personal support. Ask a proper question.

Comment: I am sorry, you are right. I will ask this [as a new question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/712417/1280). However, I have two more questions regarding your answer: 1. Where does your code after the `\makeatletter` belong: into the main document, into the subfile document, or in both? 2. I remember that `\makeatletter` is usually paired with `\makeatother`, isn't this here required?