algorithm2e + hyperref + cleveref: algorithms' lines are not numbered/referenced properly
Apparently there is something wrong in the combined use of algorithm2e, hyperref, and cleveref. (I am on the last version of MiKTeX for Windows, with all the packages updated. It used to work properly)
Consider the following MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[!t]
\caption{This is a caption}\label{alg_one}
    $a = b + c$\;
    $d = e + f$\;\nllabel{alg_one_line_two}
    $g = h + i$\;
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[!t]
\caption{This is a caption}\label{alg_two}
    $a = b + c$\;
    $d = e + f$\;
    $g = h + i$\; \nllabel{alg_two_line_three}
\end{algorithm}

Reference to algorithm: \cref{alg_one}.
Reference to line: \cref{alg_one_line_two}.

Reference to algorithm: \cref{alg_two}.
Reference to line: \cref{alg_two_line_three}.
\end{document}

This works fine and correctly prints the algorithms' lines.

However, when the hyperref package is also used, the references to algorithms' lines are typeset as "Algorithm X".

How can this be fixed?

I will look at it later.

You can fix it like this.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\nllabel}[1]
 {{\let\@currentlabel\algocf@currentlabel
  \let\@currentcounter\algocf@currentcounter
  \label{#1}}}%

\renewcommand{\algocf@nl@sethref}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\theHAlgoLine}{\thealgocfproc.#1}%
  \hyper@refstepcounter{AlgoLine}%
  \gdef\algocf@currentlabel{#1}%
  \gdef\algocf@currentcounter{AlgoLine}%
 }%
\makeatother


\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}



\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[!t]
\caption{This is a caption}\label{alg_one}
    $a = b + c$\;
    $d = e + f$\;\nllabel{alg_one_line_two}
    $g = h + i$\;
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[!t]
\caption{This is a caption}\label{alg_two}
    $a = b + c$\;
    $d = e + f$\;
    $g = h + i$\;\nllabel{alg_two_line_three} 
\end{algorithm}

Reference to algorithm: \cref{alg_one}.
Reference to line: \cref{alg_one_line_two}.

Reference to algorithm: \cref{alg_two}.
Reference to line: \cref{alg_two_line_three}.
\end{document}



Thanks a lot Ulrike, it works. I just underline that it used to properly work without the need of the patch. Who is the culprit among the three packages? Yesterday, while I was looking for a solution, I came upon https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/360#issuecomment-2453350603, thinking that the two issues were related.

@notAorB yes I know that it worked - I tested that. The concrete culprit are changes in latex + hyperref: for the tagging project we need to move the hyperref functionality into the kernel and this requires to clean up patches in hyperref. In the newest latex \refstepcounter has been extended and hyperref patches have been removed. Sadly cleveref contains lots of patches and they now start  to fall apart, but the maintainer is not responding. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/711418/2388

@notAorB but this case here there is also a small problem with algorithm2e. Its definition of \algocf@nl@sethref is not good. It should use an internal hyperref command, and it shouldn't define @currentlabel globally (I changed the second in my redefinition).

Thanks @UlrikeFischer for your answer
