# What is the recommended maintained modern (>= TexLive 2023) alternative to cleveref?

Tags: cleveref

Cleveref has seems to be unmaintained as it [produces broken references with TexLive 2023](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/708441/1280) and had its last release in 2018. It has been pointed out that it ["might be not supported anymore"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/708441/cleveref-mistakenly-showing-filename-in-external-references/708445?noredirect=1#comment1761641_708441).

What is the recommended alternative?

Comment: [`cleveref-usedon`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref-usedon) not only adds forward referencing, but also patches known bugs. So IMHO reporting unpatched `cleveref` bugs in [the `cleveref-usedon` issue tracker](https://github.com/SvenPistre/cleveref-usedon/issues) would be a good idea.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/711418/105447

Comment: @cabohah It should probably be noted that `cleveref-usedon` does not seem to be actively maintained as of now, so as a temporary workaround I uploaded the package [`cleveref-forward`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref-forward), which contains all the known fixes and improvements to `cleveref-usedon` (you may still find many open issues I wrote on the mentioned issue tracker page discussing those modifications).