Cref and xr-hyper in TeXLive 2024
In TeX Live 2024 there have been changes to the behavior of cref and xr-hyper when referencing labels defined in other documents. I'm not sure if these changes were intended or are a bug. In the following example
%main.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\begin{document}
\section{First Section} \label{section}
\begin{equation} \label{equation}
    \int f(x) dx
\end{equation}

\end{document}

%ref.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\externaldocument[main-]{main}

\begin{document}
    Equation \eqref{main-equation} in \cref{main-section}

\end{document}

the file ref.tex gets rendered as

and includes the name of the file being linked to. This is different from TeXLive 2023.
If the file name contains an underscore then this breaks the compiling, for example if main.tex is renamed to main_file.tex then pdflatex renders the above (with changed file names) as

with the underscore being interpreted incorrectly. The eqref link doesn't contain the file name.
I would like the links not to contain the filename being referenced - any ideas how to do this?

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/708441/cleveref-mistakenly-showing-filename-in-external-references

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708445/2388. With the next latex release (in the next days) or if you use now pdflatex-dev it works again.
