\newtheorem problems if I don't label chapter
I discovered a very strange behavior. If you run the following code, you will get an error (I use TexStudio and TexLive on a Mac M1):
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{ptheorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{plemma}[ptheorem]{Lemma}


\begin{document}

% For the second part of my observation, label the chapter for example like this
% \chapter{Sample Chapter}\label{a}
\chapter{Sample Chapter}
\begin{ptheorem}
    This is a theorem.
\end{ptheorem}

\begin{plemma}
    This is a lemma.
\end{plemma}
    
\end{document}


The error is
a.tex: Fehler: 17: Use of \cref@override@label@type doesn't match its definition. \begin{plemma}

Now, if you comment out one of the three usepackage commands, no error occurs. Something even stranger happens: if you just label the chapter, no error occurs either.
What is the reason?

I can only reproduce with newest latex release (Nov 2024) so possibly due to this commit. I would report at https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues

more minimally: https://texlive.net/run?%5Cdocumentclass%7Bbook%7D%0A%5Cusepackage%7Bamsthm%7D%0A%5Cusepackage%7Bhyperref%7D%0A%5Cusepackage%7Bcleveref%7D%0A%5Cnewtheorem%7Bplemma%7D%5Bchapter%5D%7BLemma%7D%0A%5Cbegin%7Bdocument%7D%0A%5Cchapter%7BS%7D%0A%5Cbegin%7Bplemma%7D%0A%20%20T%0A%5Cend%7Bplemma%7D%0A%5Cend%7Bdocument%7D

I will check later.

Edit 2024-11-19:
this has been fixed in hyperref
Old answer.
cleveref patches core LaTeX commands and makes use of internal hyperref commands. As it hasn't been updated since more than six years and so do not follow the LaTeX development (which tries to integrate more hyperref support into the kernel) these patches start to fall apart. There are a number of corrections already in the LaTeX firstaid, but it seems we missed one case.  (For more cleveref issues see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/723660, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/722909, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708445).
For now you can fix the error like this (and I will add that to the next firstaid):
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{ptheorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{plemma}[ptheorem]{Lemma}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
\def\refstepcounter@optarg[#1]#2{%
  \cref@old@refstepcounter{#2}%
  \cref@constructprefix{#2}{\cref@result}%
  \@ifundefined{cref@#1@alias}%
    {\def\@tempa{#1}}%
    {\def\@tempa{\csname cref@#1@alias\endcsname}}%
  \protected@edef\cref@currentlabel{%
    [\@tempa][\arabic{#2}][\cref@result]%
    \csname p@#2\endcsname\csname the#2\endcsname}}}      
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample Chapter}
\begin{ptheorem}
    This is a theorem.
\end{ptheorem}

\begin{plemma}
    This is a lemma.
\end{plemma}
    
\end{document}


Thank you vey much for your help and great work Ulrike!

Out of curiosity: When is usually the next firstaid?

LaTeX is released twice a year and the november release is just out, so unless we have to do a patch release sometime begin of june. But do not rely too much on this firstaids. They are no long term solution. Write the maintainer and if he doesn't react consider to drop the package and use e.g. zref-clever instead.
